# Passing data between fragment and activity getting null point exception

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

Hello Frends i am devloping A Wizard for my application on that button for next page should be enable when name has one word and mob number legth is 10.after that button which is in Fragment Activty should be enable here look at my code:

**Fragment Activity**

```
public class Intro_Main extends FragmentActivity implements ButtonenableListner{
DataModel data;
Button next;
Context context;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.l_intro_main);
    context=this;
    data=new DataModel();
    next=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    if(findViewById(R.id.fm)!=null)
    {
    Step1 s1=new Step1();
        s1.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fm,s1).commit();
    }



}
public void setname(String s){
    data.Name=s;
}
public void setnumber(String s){
    data.Number=s;
}
public void goto2(View v)
{

    Step2 s2 =new Step2();
    s2.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());
    FragmentManager fragmentManager;
    fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

    FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.enter, R.anim.exit, R.anim.pop_enter, R.anim.pop_exit);


    transaction.replace(R.id.fm, s2 );
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction.commit();
}




@Override
public void enableButton(Boolean b) {
    if (b)
        next.setEnabled(true);
    else
           next.setEnabled(false);
}
```

}

**Fragment**

```
public class Step1 extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment{
EditText name,mob;
public String s;
public ButtonenableListner listner;
Boolean s1,s2=false;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.f_step_1, container, false);
    name=(EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.editText);
    mob=(EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.editText2);

    name.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, int i3) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, int i3) {

            if (i3 != 0)
            {
                s2=true;
            }
            else
                s2=false;
            checkbothfield();
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

        }
    });
    mob.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, int i3) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, int i3) {

            if (i3==10)
            {
                s2=true;
            }
            else
                s2=false;
            checkbothfield();
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {


        }
    });

    return view;
}

private void checkbothfield() {
    if (s1==true && s2==true)
    listner.enableButton(true);
    else
        listner.enableButton(false);
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    DataModel.Name=name.getEditableText().toString();
    DataModel.Number=mob.getEditableText().toString();

    super.onStop();
}


@Override
public void onPause() {
    DataModel.Name=name.getEditableText().toString();
    DataModel.Number=mob.getEditableText().toString();
    super.onPause();
}
```

}

Please Help I am Stuck At here thank you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didnt understood your problem properly but I think you need to send data back to the Fragment activity. The way I would do it is create a public boolean in the fragmentActivity and make getter and setter functions for them.

```
public boolean dataFilled;

public boolean isDataFilled() {
    return dataFilled;
}

public void setDataFilled(boolean dataFilled) {
    this.dataFilled = dataFilled;
}
```

Using set this to false initially.

Then in the fragment use getActivity() get the activity and cast it to your FragmentActivity and call the setter function:

```
((Intro_main)getActivity).setDataFilled(true);
```

On returning back just check the value of the boolean.

****** In case you need to send data from fragmentActivity to fragment:

when calling new Step1 and arguments using :

```
Bundle bd = new Bundle;
bd.addString(key,value);
```

In the fragment OnCreate use getArguments() to get the bundle and extract the data.

Comment: Did you get your solution Parth ??